# How should I go about cleaning up a collection with 226M documents where a count query takes 6-7 minutes to run

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have a collection called "instance" that I have to archive. By archive, I mean that each document from a certain month must go into a archive table called instance_XYZmonth. For example, documents from March 2022 should go into "instance_2022-03".

My problem is that this "instance" collection is huge, it has 226M documents in it, and simply counting the documents takes 6-7 minutes.

To compound this problem, the person who designed this table created their own format for _id, which looks like this:

`f96e67f3-2bc4-4c2c-9752-d7f0be657fd1_2017-10-31:15`

Therefore, when I want to find documents that pertain to a certain date, I have to run this regex:

```
db.getCollection("instance").find({
    _id: {
        $regex: '.*_2022-03-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2]\\d|30).*'
    }
}).count()
```

This query is being run in a python script which has to run this query a couple times (since I'm using LIMIT 500 000 it has to run a couple times until there are no rows left, but each loop takes 6-7 minutes just to count documents!).

```py
        while total_documents > 0:
            logger.info(f'{total_documents} documents to cleanup')

            try:
                destination_collection.insert_many(data_to_cleanup, ordered=False)

                query = {"_id": {"$regex": regex_value}}

                source_collection.delete_many(query)
            except:
                print("Error")

            data_to_cleanup = source_collection.find({
                '_id': {
                    '$regex': regex_value
                }
            }, limit=500000)

            total_documents = data_to_cleanup.count()
```

What should I do to make my life easier?

Comment: Do you actually need the count here? Could you instead break out of the loop when you see `data_to_cleanup` is empty? (An alternative to that could be using `mongoexport` or if you're on a version of mongo that supports it, `$out`)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are always expensive and slow. You should change the data model if possible.

Maybe use `$split`

```
db.getCollection("instance").aggregate([
   { $set: { timestamp: { $last: { $split: ["$_id", "_"] } } } },
   { $set: { timestamp: { $first: { $split: ["$timestamp", ":"] } } } },
   { $set: { timestamp: { $toDate: "$timestamp" } } }
   { $match: { timestamp: ... } }
])
```

or in one line:

```
{ $set: { timestamp: { $toDate: { $first: { $split: [{ $last: { $split: ["$_id", "_"] } }, ":"] } } } } }
```

If "cleanup" means "delete" then it could be this one:

```
db.getCollection("instance").updateMany(
   {},
   [
      { $set: { timestamp: { $last: { $split: ["$_id", "_"] } } } },
      { $set: { timestamp: { $first: { $split: ["$timestamp", ":"] } } } },
      { $set: { timestamp: { $toDate: "$timestamp" } } }
   ]
)
db.getCollection("instance").deleteMany({timestamp: ...})
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. Problem is I only have Mongo 3.2.12 and the $set stage seems to have been introduced in mongo 4.2... (I should have included this in the question...)

Comment: Use `$addFields` which is the same